# How do I code where when I press a key it creates a 50% chance an animation happens?

Tags: c#

I'm making a fighting game on unity with c# and I want to make it so when I press a key (j), Theres a 50% chance he gets hit and a 50% chance he blocks it. The blocking/hitting are animations so when I press the key there's a 50/50 chance he plays each animation.

I've tried looking at yt videos, only had loot boxes and stuff for random ranges

Comment: Compute a random integer in the range [0, 1].

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random integer that's either `0` or `1` and then use it in an if-case:

```cs
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.Next(0, 2);

if(r == 0) {
  animate1();
} else {
  anmimate2();
}
```

Comment: When I do this it comes up with an error that will not go away. It says '(27,3): error CS1513: } expected', right next to the already existing curly bracket. I put one there anyway (looks like {{) and when I put one there it changes (27,4). It keeps changing whatever I do and doesn't go away.

Comment: @TomMuggeridge We can't solve that problem in the comment section with the information you've given. Please double-check that all the `{` and `}` are paired correctly.